# MakeFile creation

Tags: c, makefile

I want to make a makefile but I am so confused and I need it immediately.

I have four files(.c) an one file(.h). Three of them have main and the fourth hasn't.

main.c has main

readers.c has main

writers.c has main

funs.c has **NOT** main

The 3 of the files ( that have main ) need the functions in funs.c .

This is my makefile till now:

```
all: read write main

funs.o:funs.c
    gcc -o funs funs.c

read:funs.o
    gcc -o read readers.c funs.c

write:funs.o writers.c
    gcc -o write writers.c funs.c

main:funs.o main.c
    gcc -o main main.c funs.c -lpthread
```

Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks all for your help. This is the answer:

```
all:read write main

funs.o:funs.c
    gcc -c -o funs funs.c

read:readers.c funs.o
    gcc -o read readers.c funs.c

write:writers.c funs.o
    gcc -o write writers.c funs.c

main:main.c funs.o
    gcc -o main main.c funs.c -lpthread
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile funs.o with

```
gcc -c -o funs funs.c
```

The `-c` option makes gcc not try to link the file as a program with main.

Comment: I still get this error:

gcc -o -c funs funs.c

gcc: error: funs: No such file or directory

make: *** [funs.o] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps:

1. Create a static library for linking
2. Create each binaries

For example:

```
all: a b c

STATIC_LIBS=s.o

s.o: share.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<

a: a.c $(STATIC_LIBS)
    gcc $(STATIC_LIBS) -o $@ $<

b: b.c $(STATIC_LIBS)
    gcc $(STATIC_LIBS) -o $@ $<

c: c.c $(STATIC_LIBS)
    gcc $(STATIC_LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

1. $@ is the target
2. $< is the first dependent object